# pass value to html table

Tags: python, html, django

there is a python script **codal.py** thats print json data

peace of output:

```
{"t_a5_b": "66350750", "t_a5_c": "62832475", "t_a5_d": "56874586", "t_a15_b": "127194761", "t_a15_c": "110163944", "t_a15_d": "62220525", "t_a34_b": "371949378", ...}
```

then run script in **view.py**

```
def external(request):
    out= run([sys.executable,'/home/masih/projects/django/buttonpython/buttonpython/codal.py'],shell=False,stdout=PIPE)

    return render(request,'home.html',{'json_view':out.stdout})
```

in **home.html** file i can get json data by `{{json_view}}`
how can i use json_view value in html table
eg: `"t_a5_b": "66350750"`

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>ta_a5_b.value</th>
    <th>something</th>
    <th>something</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the external script returns a json string, you need to parse it to an python json object. To do this you can use

```
import json
def external(request):
    out= run([sys.executable,'/home/masih/projects/django/buttonpython/buttonpython/codal.py'],shell=False,stdout=PIPE)
    parsed_json = json.loads(out)
    return render(request,'home.html',{'json_view':parsed_json})
```

And in your template you can access this dictionary with the curly bracket syntax like so:

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>{{ json_view.ta_a5_b }}</th>
    <th>something</th>
    <th>something</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If your script outputs already a valid python json object, you just need to use the modification of the template I suggested.